# Documents on MicroSD

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, phone

Is there a way to view documents which are stored on my MicroSD in [Document Viewer](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.docviewer) (Ubuntu Core App Developers)? In [File Manager](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.filemanager) I've to enter the password before I could see the files. Creating symlinks seems one possible way but it might be that I've overseen one little thing.

Music, Videos... which are also stored on my MicroSD can be used by other applications. All folders have equal rights...

Thanks.